# What is a word called that can function as multiple other types of words?

Tags: word-classes

Say we have a word W such that it is, in some context, appropriate to use as: a noun, a verb, an adjective, an adverb, and an interjection.

Is there a particular name for these types of multi-class words?

Comment: [***nounification of a verb / verbification of a noun***](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/nounification-of-a-verb-or-verbification-of-a-noun.2670821/) are so common in English that the "name" you seek is probably just ***word***.

Comment: Yes, this is a better fit for Linguistics than English.

Comment: Though there isn't a special linguistic term for it. Analytic languages like Vietnamese or English have thousands of words that can occur in constructions filling the roles of noun, verb, or adjective, not to mention subordinate conjunction and preposition. POS is not a significant category at the lexical level in such languages; the part of speech is determined by the construction, not the word.

Comment: You've answered your own question: 'multi-category'' or 'multi-classified' are good enough terms.

Comment: Wouldn't `homonym` fit—words with the same orthographic form but with (slightly) different meanings?

Comment: @ScottSchupbach That won't work because some homonyms belong to the same word class (POS): for example "bank" (financial institution) and "bank" (sloping margin of a river) are homonyms but they are also both nouns. The OP was looking for a term for words that belong to two or more classes, and unlike homonyms they don't necessarily have the same pronunciation.

Comment: @BillJ I wasn't saying that all homonym pairs are different word types, just that what the OP was describing could fall under the umbrella term homonym. And homonyms don't necessarily have to be pronounced the same way (those are homophones). Words with the same spelling are still homonyms even if they're pronounced differently.

Comment: @ScottSchupbach No, it couldn't. You're missing the point. The OP is specifically looking for a term that covers words that can belong to more than one class. Homonyms don't meet that requirement for the reason I gave you. FYI Homonymy is the phenomenon where distinct lexical items happen to be pronounced and spelled alike, as in the "bank" example that I gave you. The fact that such homonyms exist rules out the term 'homonym' as being a suitable answer to the OP's question. 'Multi-category' or 'multi-classified' are the best terms I can think off, and the ones used in all my grammar books.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways of interpreting it.

1. Treating it as a single word with multiple categories. The different forms sometimes have subtly different shades of meaning, so some people don't like this way.
2. Treating them as a form of **polysemy** - multiple meanings for a single word. With this, you are treating the word as a noun basically as a separate word from the word as a verb.
3. Treating one as the "main form" and the rest as forms **zero-derived** from that form. That is, making them related, but separate words. This analysis works best when you can find a primary form.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, a working definition of 'word' needs to be posited. Here, the non-well-defined 'orthographic word of given form, but with homographs being distinct words' is chosen (so 'periodic' roughly = 'happening occasionally', and 'periodic' = 'compounds etc in which the iodine exists in oxidation state VII', are two different words).

Words obviously related (so not homographs), of the same form, but being different parts of speech, have been called **intercategorial polysemes**. [Zawada: [Conceptual integration and intercategorial polysemy](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/10228190701640124?journalCode=rlms20)]

And an extract from an article by Zawada at [ResearchGate](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/233083057_Conceptual_integration_and_intercategorial_polysemy):

> Conceptual integration, also called blending, was proposed as a
>   cognitive mechanism to account for creativity in thought and language.
>   A particular proposal was made that conceptual integration can account
>   for monocategorial lexical polysemy in instances such as safeA in
>   sentences such as *The child is safe* and *The beach is safe*. In this
>   paper the theory of conceptual integration is presented, and it is
>   shown that it can also account for a variety of instances of
>   intercategorial polysemy, for example in N–V alternations such as *sail* [The sail; They sail]
>   and *ache*, as well as an example of A–N–V alternation, namely *wide* [in cricket jargon].

Comment: a) Taking the cited idea one step further: one could talk of *monocategorial polysemy* only if one doesn't care for subdividing the categories, unless one might accept that a word's categorization may be ambivalent in situ and thus not strictly divisable, but that would potentially create another category, e.g. for *swimming*. b) One can figure that *headword* in a lexicon is also a Part of Speech, thereby all words are trivially multicategorial, hypothetically, or one ignores this, but then intercategorial polysemy is nevertheless a kind of pleonasm, unless there were intercategorial unisemy.

Comment: Yes. I'm ambivalent myself, seeing 'painting' in 'Brown's deftly painting his daughter was a joy to behold' as on a noun-verb cline, as posited in Quirk et al, but 'galore' as both quantifier and adjective at the same time. 'Many gay/resplendent ...'.